# Console access to Dokku's PostgreSQL plugin?

Tags: postgresql, dokku

Is there a way to get console access to [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku)'s [PostgreSQL plugin](https://github.com/Kloadut/dokku-pg-plugin)? On Heroku I'd do `heroku pg:psql`. Is this possible in a Dokku environment and if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is in fact a way to do this directly with the `dokku-pg-plugin`.

The command `postgresql:restore <db> < dump_file.sql` connects to the specified database and restores it with the provided dump file. If you simply omit the dump file part (`< dump_file.sql`), a `psql` console session opens.

Since `postgresql:restore <db>` is semantically not the best way to open a console session, I have opened a [pull request](https://github.com/Kloadut/dokku-pg-plugin/pull/49) to add the command `postgresql:console <db>`.

So, until my PR is merged, the options for opening a `psql` console for a database are either:

- doing it manually with `psql -h 172.17.42.1 -p <port> -U root db` with the `<port>` and `password` taken from the output of `dokku postgresql:info <db>`,
- using the semantically incorrect command `dokku postgresql:restore <db>`, or
- <strike>use [my forked and patched version](https://github.com/dschwertfeger/dokku-pg-plugin) of the plugin which adds the command `postgresql:console <db>`.</strike>

**Edit:**
The owner of the [`dokku-pg-plugin`](https://github.com/Kloadut/dokku-pg-plugin) has merged my pull request. If you're using this plugin and are looking for a way to access your PostgreSQL console with it, you might want to update it to the latest version. Once you have done that, you can use the command `postgresql:console <db>` to open a `psql` session to the specified database.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to run "CREATE EXTENSION" using this console sesssion? I am getting "HINT: Must be superuser to create this extension". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for my Rails app that I'm running on Dokku:

`dokku run <app-name> rails db`

That brought up the console for the PostgreSQL container I created (via `dokku postgresql:create <db>`). I couldn't figure out another way to get at the PostgreSQL instance in that container, short of attempting to directly connect to the DB, with the connection info/credentials listed when you do this:

`dokku postgresql:info <db>`

I haven't tried that, though I suspect it would work.

Comment: Yes, this works for a Rails app because it's built in and opens a Rails db console. I was looking for a more general way to open a `psql` console session, though. It's true that you can manually connect with `psql` using the connection parameters from `dokku postgresql:info <db>` but it's tedious to do. Thanks anyways!